# How to get android device model number connected to a PC via USB?

Tags: usb, hardware, android-sdk

How do I get the android phone model number from a Windows PC connected via USB, provided all the USB device drivers are installed properly? Is there anyway to get it via Android SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to get it by the adb command.

But you can get it programmably with the SDK. There is a class **Build** which have many information of the current running phone, such as you wanted model number can be got by the **Build.MODEL**.

Comment: hey, thanks for the pointer, found out the adb command:

adb shell cat /system/build.prop | grep "ro.product.model"

Comment: For anyone else stumbling across this old question, the above comment requires root.  On a non-rooted phone: `adb shell getprop ro.product.model`. Also of potential use is `adb shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer`. For a full list of properties, just `adb shell getprop`